# TYPO3 : add multiple additionalAttributes values

Tags: typo3

On typo3 I'm overriding an input of a form like this :

```
    <f:render partial="Field/Field" arguments="{element: element, doNotShowLabel: 1}" contentAs="elementContent">
        <f:render partial="Field/Field" section="label" arguments="{_all}"/>
        <f:form.select
                property="{element.identifier}"
                id="{element.uniqueIdentifier}"
                options="{formvh:translateElementProperty(element: element, property: 'options')}"
                class="{element.properties.elementClassAttribute} form-control"
                errorClass="{element.properties.elementErrorClassAttribute}"
                
                additionalAttributes="{formvh:translateElementProperty(element: element, property: 'fluidAdditionalAttributes')}"
                prependOptionLabel="{f:render(partial: 'Field/Field', section: 'label', arguments: '{_all}') -> f:spaceless() -> f:format.stripTags()}"
                prependOptionValue=""
        />
    </f:render>
```

I want to add another value on the "additionalAttributes" by adding an aria-describedby

I tried this :

```
additionalAttributes="{aria-describedby: 'help-block',formvh:translateElementProperty(element: element, property: 'fluidAdditionalAttributes')}"
```

and I got this error : "The argument "additionalAttributes" was registered with type "array", but is of type "string" in view helper "TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\ViewHelpers\Form\SelectViewHelper"."

Someone have an idea to solve this issue ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can use the generic `aria` attribute instead:

```
<f:render partial="Field/Field" arguments="{element: element, doNotShowLabel: 1}" contentAs="elementContent">
    <f:render partial="Field/Field" section="label" arguments="{_all}"/>
    <f:form.select
            property="{element.identifier}"
            id="{element.uniqueIdentifier}"
            options="{formvh:translateElementProperty(element: element, property: 'options')}"
            class="{element.properties.elementClassAttribute} form-control"
            errorClass="{element.properties.elementErrorClassAttribute}"
            aria="{describedby: 'help-block'}"
            
            additionalAttributes="{formvh:translateElementProperty(element: element, property: 'fluidAdditionalAttributes')}"
            prependOptionLabel="{f:render(partial: 'Field/Field', section: 'label', arguments: '{_all}') -> f:spaceless() -> f:format.stripTags()}"
            prependOptionValue=""
    />
</f:render>
```

See \TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractTagBasedViewHelper::initialize.

Answer (score 0):

I think that here: `formvh:translateElementProperty(element: element, property: 'fluidAdditionalAttributes')` could be the problem. `formvh` is another ViewHelper right? That returns no array I think.

Comment: yes it's another ViewHelper, @sebo solved my issue